# 3 divs are expanding outside of the flex container div causing the elements to overlap

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overlapping

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzDjK.png

(update)  i believe i found the root cause of the issue. say the container has 2 divs in it and the height is 300. if i add a 3rd div, the height becomes 320. i have to stop the height from changing because another div is added. i want the 3rd div to squeeze into the 300. how do i stop the 3rd div from changing the height of the container?

```
    <div id="flex-container" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column">
           <div id=" a " style="flex-grow:1 ">
           </div>
           <div id="b " style="flex-grow: 1 ">
           </div>
           <div id="c " style="flex-grow: 1 ">
           </div>
    </div>
```

(original) hi there. if you look at the image. the current home page has div A and div C showing when you land on it. when you change the value in a drop box, b is added to the flex container. adding b pushes C out of the flex container causing it to overlap. i dont understand what im doing wrong. i would like to keep all 3 divs within the flex container. please give me some feedback.

---

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score -3):

I am not sure if I have understood your question but I will try to answer it.

I think you can give it a fixed size, please try this CSS:

```
#divId { width: 500px; height: 600px; overflow: auto }
```

Comment: hi there. i appreciate the assistance. i believe i find the root cause of the issue. say the container has 2 divs in it and the height is 300. if i add a 3rd div, the height becomes 320. i have to stop the height from changing because another div is added. i want the 3rd div to squeeze into the 300. how do i stop the 4rd div from changing the height of the container?